# Eclipse does not detect named parameter in a constructor of a class imported from external library

Tags: eclipse, scala, apache-spark

Eclipse does not detect named parameter `pollingPeriodInSeconds`. It is underlined with red curly line. Please see last line in code below.

`RSSInputDStream` is a class imported from `com.github.catalystcode.fortis.spark.streaming.rss.RSSInputDStream`. The library is added to Libraries of Java Build Path in Eclipse. Why Eclipse does not detect constructor of RSSInputDStream correctly?

```
package com.cnnnewsandtrends

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Seconds
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel

import com.github.catalystcode.fortis.spark.streaming.rss.RSSInputDStream

object main 
{

  def main(args: Array[String])
  {
    // Create Spark session object.
    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder
      .appName("CNNNewsAndTrends")
      .master("local[*]")
      .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///C:/temp") // Necessary to work around a Windows bug in Spark 2.0.0; omit if you're not on Windows.
      .getOrCreate()

    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

    // Setup a stream context.
    val batchInterval = 10
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(spark.sparkContext, Seconds(batchInterval))

    val urls : Seq[String] = Seq("http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss")
    val stream = new RSSInputDStream
                (
                    urls, 
                    Map[String, String]
                    (
                      "User-Agent" -> "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36"
                    ),
                    ssc, 
                    StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY, 
                    pollingPeriodInSeconds = batchInterval
                )



  }

}
```

Comment: Is the class visible in the _Package/Project Explorer_ below the _Referenced Libraries_ node? Which Eclipse version? With which Java version is the JAR compiled? Which compiler compliance level is set in the project? Is there a `module-info.java` file in the default package?

Comment: @howlger yes, it's below the Referenced Libraries. 

Eclipse version:
Scala IDE build of Eclipse SDK
Build id: 4.7.0-vfinal-2017-09-29T14:34:02Z-Typesafe

Java version: 1.8.0_231

Where can I find the compiler compliance level?
Should I find `module-info.java` file in my package `com.cnnnewsandtrends`?

Comment: Eclipse 4.7 is pretty old, the current version is 4.13. `module-info.java` is only relevant for Java 9 or higher. The compiler compliance can be set/viewed in _Project > Properties: Java Compiler_. If you use Java 8, also the used JARs must not be compiled with a higher Java version.